# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined google maps api

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I'm a beginner trying to create a simple geocoding engine using the google maps api.

The issue of this is using this code I get one working section of the console log and then an error with undefined.

[image]

I've created some simple almost working code below

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.getJSON("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&key=AIzaSyAyS3rSKQPYcxCO9OBdda6qaFRWB4CDPak", function(result){
            $.each(result, function(i, field){
                var result = field[0]
                console.log(result.address_components[3].long_name)

       });
        });
    });
});
</script>


<button>Get JSON data</button>

<div></div>
```

My question is what's going on here, why do I get a valid response, i.e. mountain view and then the typeerror.

Comment: I added answer, hope it will help you to understand the issue ans work as per your expectation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '3' of undefined

This statement states that `address_components` object is not defined.

**Observation :**

You are trying to iterate the top most level array which is `results`. hence, in this case your loop executing fail after one iteration.

Iterate `res.results[0].address_components` instead of whole `result`.

**Try this :**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.getJSON("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&key=AIzaSyAyS3rSKQPYcxCO9OBdda6qaFRWB4CDPak", function(res){
            var result = res.results;
            var addressComponents = res.results[0].address_components;
            for (var i in addressComponents) {
              console.log(addressComponents[i].long_name);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Get JSON data</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to access address_component from the response then you need to try below code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("button").click(function(){
    $.getJSON("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&key=AIzaSyAyS3rSKQPYcxCO9OBdda6qaFRWB4CDPak", function(result){ 

        console.log(result.results); // as result is an object (response from the API) and object has a property named 'results'

         // itteration for itterating result.results array 
        $.each(result.results, function(i, field){ 

            //for each loop to itterate the array 'field.address_components'
              field.address_components.forEach(function(element){
                console.log(element.long_name);
            });

   });
    });
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `field[0]` that you try to access does not exist - the API returns a (serialized) *object*, not an array.

You have to navigate to its `results` property first before you can begin iterating.

```js
fetch('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&key=AIzaSyAyS3rSKQPYcxCO9OBdda6qaFRWB4CDPak')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(resJSON => {
    const results = resJSON.results;
    const address_components = resJSON.results[0].address_components;
    address_components.forEach(address_component => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(address_component));
    });
  });
```